# How do I display progress?

Tags: php, progress

I have a cycle. it holds quite a long time, I need to visualize the process work. how to do this?

```
while ($csvIterator->next()) {
 //a lot of code...
 visualizeProcess();
 }
```

Comment: Do you want to send a part of the page before the complete script is executed, or display some sort of progress bar?

Comment: Depends on EVERYTHING, but I'm sure you'll need the `echo` function.

Comment: Echo won't do anything as far as progress goes. Nothing that is echo'd will make it to the user's browser until the page is sent back, meaning your progress would go from 0% (don't have page) to 100% (do have page) You need to use Javascript.

Comment: @MoarCodePlz Not true. I have long - running script in production (up to hours) it uses echoes to display the progress. Everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

-This assumes you are using PHP for web-based applications.

In short, there is no easy way to do this. There are a lot of areas in which you would need to design your application smartly to handle it (ie: if you're building a page piece by piece then what happens if its supposed to be secured? You'll need to implement SSL and make sure that all AJAX calls are encrypted). Basically what you need to do is have the script executable in blocks, instead of having a loop that does the operation in its entirety on its own. For instance, have a php file that takes an integer as a query string and then uses that integer to do a different action. Once the integer is equal to a certain number you can be sure that everything you needed to do has been done and therefore progress makes it to 100%. You cannot have PHP send a page piece by piece back to a browser, which is what it seems you are proposing to do. You need to use AJAX calls (assuming this is a web application instead of a command line application). Do something like the following:

1. Create a PHP file that takes in an int via query string. Have the integer that is passed along dictate the action that the PHP script undertakes (ie: 0 = get all session variables allotted, 1 = connect to the database and get the data you need to parse and push it into session, 2 = parse the data from session and do something).
2. Create a PHP file that will be served to the client as the base page that will show the progress. From this page you will need to use Javascript to request the page mentioned in 1 with the various query strings. The AJAX calls that you issue have success and failure handlers, and in these you will be able to change what is being displayed on the page to reflect how the process is coming along.

In short there is no easy way to do progress bars for web applications due to the nature of their distribution. I suggest that you look in to the way GET and POST requests work, the functionality of web servers, and the way that the PHP handler works w/ Apache to get a better idea of why your initial approach isn't viable.

Answer (score 1):

You really need more detail in your question. if you need a detailed percentage bar indicator like [image: loading bar]

then you need to divide your loop data into pieces (either using the iteration count/total number of iterations or bytes read etc).

[**THIS GUIDE**](http://www.redips.net/javascript/ajax-progress-bar/) will provide you with the necessary knowledge to do that.

If, on the other hand you just need a loading indicator like the famous [image: ajax load gif] then all you gatta do (let's assume you have jquery and your script only processes) is

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    $("#myLoaderGif").show();
    $.get("myPHPScript.php", function(data){
           alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
           $("#myLoaderGif").hide();
    })});
```

This example assumes you have an `<img id="myLoaderGif">` tag with your loading image and some element with `id = myButton` that initiates the script and you're using get to retrieve data

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` or `var_dump` in the middle of your loop. Also [implicit_flush](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-implicit-flush.php) might affect verbosity.

Comment: Both echo and var_dump will only make it back to the client's machine once the script has run in its entirety. This wouldn't be displaying anything in terms of progress.

Comment: See my comment to the question itself.

Comment: If a user is trying to "visualize" a process instead of just notify a user of progress, I doubt they are running PHP via command line. Granted if you're running PHP via command line you can echo and var_dump all you'd like, but seeing as that is a small subset of the primary functionality / intended functionality of PHP I would find it odd that the user didn't explicitly state this was being run from CMD if it was.

Comment: @J0HN but I'm not working, possibly due to the fact that I use inside file_get_contents

Comment: I'm using PHP via browser. I wouldn't post this if I was not sure this is possible. And mentioned production scripts work with Apache, with almost standard configuration. Can't post php -i or apache httpd.conf now (maybe on Monday), but believe me, that WORKS with PHP and apache.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use is JavaScript, but you can use

```
flush()
```

function, too